# Django dynamic categories

Tags: python, django

I have the following task:
Create a blog where the create blog post form looks like the following(in Django 1.8.17):

- There is a title, content char/textfield
- There is a category field which is a list, and you have to choose one
- If you choose "Others" a CharField appears (or it can exist before that, but I am not allowed to write inside it)
- When I choose "Others" and fill the charfield, it creates a new
  Category which I can choose later.

My models.py now:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.OneToOneField(Category)
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    author  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={"id" : self.id})
```

That's what I got now. It looks like in the form:
[image: Screenshot]

So my question is: How can I add categories to the "Category" field and how can I update it with one charfield?

Comment: Have you got any question?

Comment: Yeah, I stuct at, how can I put "choices" in the Category field?

Comment: Do you want to disallow categories that are already in a blog relation? I question the oneToOneField here as it makes little sense to allow a category only for one post. Usually categories are used to group multiple posts.

Comment: No  I dont want. I want one category to multiple posts but every post has only one category

Comment: You're describing a `ForeignKey(Category)`  in your `Post` class (and not a `OneToOneField`)..

Answer (score 0):

To create your first set of example categories, use the /admin screens to populate the table.  You can also populate the database from the command line with:

```
 manage.py shell
```

This gives you a python shell in which you can create and save objects.  [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api)

To get your second bit of functionality will require that there be a category they can select that indicates that the textfield is their actual preferred category, eg. 'my new category...'

The easiest way is probably to make that text field part of the form, and add some logic in the view that saves the text as a category, and then saves their submission with that category selected - ie they don't add the category first, then select it, then write the post, they just write the category and the post and submit it all together.

If you want to update the drop-down so they select their category, you will either need to refresh the page (risks losing whatever they've written in their post) or use javascript (jquery I guess?) to save their category to the server without a refresh.